# Is there a simple way to convert a Unicode text file to PDF on the command line on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, pdf, text, unicode

What is a simple way to convert a Unicode text file to PDF on the command line on macOS?

One can open a text file in e.g. TextEdit and print it as a PDF. Is there a command line equivalent?

Answer (score 9):

The following has been tested on Mac OS 10.12.1.

To convert a Unicode text file text.txt to a pdf file text.pdf:

```
textutil -convert html test.txt
cupsfilter test.html > test.pdf
```

To specify font:

```
textutil -font 'Menlo Regular' -fontsize 11 -convert html test.txt
cupsfilter test.html > test.pdf
```

Comment: `> cupsfilter release-notes.html` 
`> cupsfilter: No filter to convert from text/html to application/pdf.` I've tried you method but got this error, maybe do you know what's wrong ?

Comment: @Zohar81 I am afraid not. Since writing this answer I have moved towards a more heavyweight solution where I use XeLaTeX to convert the text file to pdf.

Comment: It is working in osx Monterey 12.6. Thank you, Anders.

Answer (score 1):

https://pandoc.org/ can convert from text to PDF (and much more).
Basic invocation:

```
pandoc input.txt -o output.pdf
```

Comment: This is an ***online converter*** which pretty much throws any expected  privacy right out the window.  For security purposes, I highly suggest people avoid this.

Comment: @Allan No, it absolutely is not. https://pandoc.org/installing.html